# How to check if double is NEGATIVE_INFINITY in Java

Tags: java, double

How do I check if double is NEGATIVE_INFINITY and not POSITIVE_INFINITY?
There is only one method in Double class `isInfinite()` which checks whether the double is infinite or not but it returns true in both cases if it's positive and if it's negative. So is there another way to check the specific infinity (negative or positive)?

Comment: What about `if (x==Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)` ?

Comment: oh it actually worked. thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible ways to check if a double `x` specifically holds negative infinity:

```
if (Double.isInfinite(x) && x < 0) ...
```

or simply

```
if (x==Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) ...
```

Comment: i actually wanted to try to code it in the second way but it just seemed.. off? i thought it was used to only declare a variable as negative infinity.